# SpringBoot app. accessing 2 DataSources using JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a SpringBoot app. that has to access to different datasources to export data from 1 to another (1 local datasource and another remote datasource)

This is how  my persistenceConfig looks like

```
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    public  JdbcTemplate localJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(localDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public  JdbcTemplate remoteJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(remoteDataSource());
    }



    @Bean
    public DataSource localDataSource(){

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(getLocalDbPoolSize());
        config.setMinimumIdle(5);
        config.setDriverClassName(getLocalDbDriverClassName());
        config.setJdbcUrl(getLocalDbJdbcUrl());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", getLocalDbUser());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", getLocalDbPwd());

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource remoteDataSource(){

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(getRemoteDbPoolSize());
        config.setMinimumIdle(5);
        config.setDriverClassName(getRemoteDbDriverClassName());
        config.setJdbcUrl(getRemoteDbJdbcUrl());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", getRemoteDbUser());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", getRemoteDbPwd());

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
}
```

But when I init my app I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: localDataSource,remoteDataSource
```

I also tried to user qualified beans, as follows:

```
@Bean(name = "localJdbcTemplate")
    public  JdbcTemplate localJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(localDataSource());
    }


    @Bean(name = "remoteJdbcTemplate")
    public  JdbcTemplate remoteJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(remoteDataSource());
    }



    @Bean(name = "localDataSource")
    public DataSource localDataSource(){

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(getLocalDbPoolSize());
        config.setMinimumIdle(5);
        config.setDriverClassName(getLocalDbDriverClassName());
        config.setJdbcUrl(getLocalDbJdbcUrl());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", getLocalDbUser());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", getLocalDbPwd());

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }


    @Bean(name = "remoteDataSource")
    public DataSource remoteDataSource(){

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(getRemoteDbPoolSize());
        config.setMinimumIdle(5);
        config.setDriverClassName(getRemoteDbDriverClassName());
        config.setJdbcUrl(getRemoteDbJdbcUrl());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", getRemoteDbUser());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", getRemoteDbPwd());

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
```

but then I got this other error:

```
A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'transactionManager' not loaded because @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find a primary bean from beans 'remoteDataSource', 'localDataSource'
```

I also tried

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
            DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
            DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
            DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
            DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

but then I got

```
A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' that could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bean names to qualify them:

```
@Bean(name = "localDataSource")
public DataSource localDataSource() {
  ...
}

@Bean(name = "remoteDataSource")
public DataSource remoteDataSource() {
  ...
}
```

**Please note:** You have to do the same for your JdbcTemplate beans - just give them a name and it will work.
See the Spring JavaDoc for more Information: [Bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#value--)

```
@Bean(name = "localJdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate localJdbcTemplate() {
  return new JdbcTemplate(localDataSource());
}
```

When you use your JdbcTemplate beans within your export service implementation via autowiring (@Autowired), you need to use @Qualifier to qualify them:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("localJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("remoteJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bean gets its name from the method name, providing name attribute just makes it explicit (keeping the name the same as the method name). Overall suggestion about `@Bean(name="...")` and `@Qualifier` didn't fix the error for me.

I set up sample project with two embedded databases and got the same error as the aothor. Spring suggestion was to annotate one of the DataSource beans as `@Primary` and, in fact, this fixes the error. Usually it happens, when some other application parts want to see only one or one primary DataSource, if several present.

What seems to be a better solution is to disable not needed autoconfiguration beans keeping rest of the code as it is:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

or:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

depending on which annotations are in use.

If author doesn't use any JPA provider and operates directly with JdbcTemplate it may be a suitable solution.

Comment: This was the solution in my case. The accepted answer did not work for me.